# ASP.NET - Running .NET App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.NET Core 1.0. I followed the instructions provided at [this link](http://www.mithunvp.com/asp-net-core-visual-studio-code-yeoman/). I am able to successfully load static pages via lite-server. However, I cannot figure out how to render server-side pages.

For example, the link above explains how to get index.html appearing. However, when I visit http://localhost:[port]/, I kind of would expect to see the contents of Views/Home/Index.cshtml.

How do I execute server-side pages?

Updated:
Here is my project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "MyApp"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {}
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "bower install",
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp min"
    ]
  }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your `project.json` file.

Comment: No, you shouldn't see the contents of your Razor (.cshtml) pages in the browser. You should see the results of rendering that Razor page.

Comment: @aguafrommars I have provided my project.json file as requested. Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: @mason - I guess that is my question. How do I see the rendered version of the Razor page?

Comment: Did you try to run `dnx web`command ?

Comment: What does your Startup.cs file look like?

Comment: @aguafrommars - When I try to run `dnx web`, I see "'dnx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I thought about installing it. But, then I thought dnx had been deprecated for just "dotnet". For that reason, I'm not sure what to install to get the code to run.

Comment: @mason - I've added my Startup.cs file to the question.

Comment: it's not yet deprecated, dotnet CLI will be available with `rc2`, it's unstable today. install `'dnvm` for your OS, read the doc here :  https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/

Comment: @aguafrommars - Much closer. I still see "Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'.

Comment: At the bottom of the article, there are instructions on installing lite-server. Did you do that too? (Without a server, ASP.NET won't work)

Comment: @Tim - Yes, I have lite-server installed. It give me "Cannot GET /" in the browser.

Comment: If there is a static file of same name as MVC file, static file is loaded. Have you removed the index.html file??

Comment: @SRQCoder - I did remove the index.html file from the wwwroot directory. I've confirmed there isn't one elsewhere.

Comment: Was the index.html ever viewed in your browser? If so, you may be seeing cached content - a possibility.

Comment: @SRQCoder - The static version of index.html was viewable. In fact, I can still view it if I rename a file from "temp.html" to "index.html". However, I cannot see any views generated server-side by ASP.NET it seems. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I know you started out with the Yeoman tutorial. Are you running the app inside the VS IDE now? If so, set a debug breakpoint and follow the execution - or break something and see what the stack trace looks like if you don't like the debug windows.

Comment: @SRQCoder - Strange. Opened in VS IDE and I was able to start the app without any issue. The app runs from http://localhost:5000/ through visual studio. Tried to open the app again by running `lite-server` from the command line, and I still get the "Cannot GET / " error.

Comment: VS IDE launch `IIS Express` by default, it's why you can run you app, but you can debug your command defined in your `project.json` too.

Comment: but `lite-server` will not serve your razor views. Did you run `dnu restore` before running `dnx web` ?

Comment: @aguafrommars - I did do a `dnu restore`. I ended up rebooting my machine. When I came back, it worked. But, `dnx web` doesn't have the nice live reload capabilities of `lite-server`. Seems like a step back

Comment: I don't agree, it have reload capabilies, actualy you don't have to reload the razor view, `Roslyn` compile your code each time you modify it. However, it doesn't work when you attach a debuger.

Comment: I ran `dnx web` from the command line. I then changed the Views/Home/Index.cshtml file. I just added `<h1>Hello</h1>` and it did not trigger a refresh. I had to manually stop the web server and start it again before seeing Hello.

Answer (score -1):

All of the view pages you create in the Views folder and have the extension .cshtml are loaded via a controller - generally, by convention, of the same name as the method within the controller. So, for one of these View pages to fire, a corresponding controller action (method) must execute.

In order to get the controller's method to fire, there needs to be an appropriate route configured. I didn't see in the tutorial you referenced any indication that MVC was 'enabled'. Even though you have a reference to MVC in the above project.json file, MVC must be configured within the startup.cs file. And a route needs to be configured.

What you're Yeoman tutorial has shown you is how to create an 'empty' project - not an MVC one.

I hope this helps out :)

Comment: If you're not sure whether they've set MVC up, then you should ask for clarification on the question rather than trying to answer an incomplete question.

Comment: Yes, Mason, I thought about that, but it's very clear from the tutorial that an empty project was created.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the tutorial says, that's external to the question. We're not debugging a tutorial, we're finding out what Zach did wrong. And if we need to know more details, we should ask for them, as I did. And after I did ask, it turns out he *did* set up MVC, meaning your answer is not relevant. The important thing to remember is to wait until you have enough information to sufficiently answer *before* answering.